# Rspec for Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In Model

```
validates :max_panels, :if => :depot?, :numericality => true
```

I am writing an rspec for the above validation and found something confusing

```
it { should validate_numericality_of(:max_panels) if :depot? }
```

When ran this test case got error like

```
1) Site spec for valid sites - Validations 
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_numericality_of(:max_panels) if :depot? }
       Expected errors to include "is not a number" when max_panels is set to "abcd", got errors: ["format can't be blank (nil)", "illumination can't be blank (nil)", "illumination_period can't be blank (nil)", "vertical_size  must be between 0.1 and 30 metres (nil)", "horizontal_size  must be between 0.1 and 200 metres (nil)", "site_authorisation_id  must have a valid authorisation (nil)"]
```

But when i added unless in my test case it got passed, Can anybody please explain me regarding it as i am new to Rspec. Also suggest how i can write the correct rspec for above validation.

```
it { should validate_numericality_of(:max_panels) if :depot? unless true }
```

Comment: As a note `if :depot?` will always be true it is not calling a method in this case but rather using Symbol itself `:depot?` as a conditional which will always be a truthy value: e.g. `:depot? ? true : false #=> true`

Comment: How can i write Rspec for above Model validation

Comment: Fair i miss read the docs try `it { should validate_numericality_of(:max_panels) if subject.depot? }`

Comment: Why -2 When so much discussion and Stack Overflow topper is also in discussion

Comment: @GouravNaik: Your question lacks details, which prompts users to request more info from you. This is a sign of bad question, hence the downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Brief looking at the source of `validate_numericality_of` matcher shows that it doesn't contain explicit support for `:if` conditions. This may be handled by base matchers, but anyway, here's an alternative idea about the testing: prepare object, attempt validation and check error messages.

Something along the lines of:

```
describe 'numericality validation' do
  subject(:instance) { described_class.new(params) }
  before { instance.valid? }

  context 'when depot' do
    let(:params) { { max_panels: 'abcd', depot: true} }
    it { expect(instance.errors.messages[:max_panels]).to eq 'is not a number' }
  end

  context 'when not depot' do
    let(:params) { { max_panels: 'abcd', depot: false} }

    it { expect(instance.errors.messages[:max_panels]).to eq nil }
  end


end
```

Comment: I believe the if portion would be handled by pure ruby and I generally also recommend checking validity for thoroughness. e.g. `{expect(subject).to be_invalid }`

Comment: @engineersmnky: "expect to be invalid" will be quite useless there, because that model has a ton of other validations which will also fail on this near-empty instance. Also the reverse "expect to be valid" will, of course, fail (for the same reason)

Comment: Yes I guess that is true. I generally build a completely valid object and then check its validations strictly in isolation. This way I do not have to rely on what the error message returned is as much as that the object is not valid and that it's errors contain only the attribute I am testing.

Comment: Test case failed when depot, expected 'is not a number' but got nil

Comment: @GouravNaik: maybe it's string access vs symbol access (`errors['max_panels']`), maybe something else. Do some debugging.

Answer (score 0):

`unless true` will never happen, so your `it` is likely not running the should and looks as though it passed.

unless is not rspec, that is pure ruby. You have told rspec you have a test (`it`), and that the `should` will never run. This will show as a passed test since the `it` did not fail.

Another part of this is to not use conditionals in your tests. They should be predictable. Don't use if or unless to determine whether or not to run assertions.

Lastly: Your error from rspec shows a list of validation errors, not of them say anything about what you're asserting. This test has multiple issues, but is flawed even in the `should`

Comment: if i give unless :depot? also its working getting passed. How can i correct Rspec for it

Comment: ``:depot`` is likely also 'true' meaning you said ``unless true`` there as well.

Comment: @GouravNaik: `:depot?` is a truthy value. Why are you putting conditions in tests like this, again?

Comment: So what is the proper way for that validation. It will help me a lot

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to write rspec for this validates :max_panels, :if => :depot?, :numericality => true

Comment: Gourav read my edit. Your should is flawed, it contains no errors of which you're asserting. Look into should_raise and be specific. Include will checkt hat the array has that error, you should use that and a regex. Turn off the conditionals, they're unpredictable.

Comment: SO what will be the test case for my Model validation kindly suggest

Comment: I can't help you write your tests without knowing your models, but I can tell you what's wrong, which I did above.

Comment: Thank you, i will try with something but why down vote for my question.